# Foreign-key-columns missing in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to retrieve all the data of a datatable in a datagridview.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
```

Ok, thats really simple but the problem is, that not all columns have been created. All the foreign-key-columns are missing. It seems to be the default-behaviour. I don´t want to turn off AutoGenerateColumns-property and create the columns manually.

Is there an easy way to generate really ALL columns in the datagridview?

Comment: Could you count manually how many columns are in DataGridView displayed and also place `MessageBox.Show(dataTable1.Columns.Count.ToString());` and check that number too

Comment: The numbers are identical. The missing columns have been not created.

Comment: That means problem is not in line you wrote up but code where you populate your datatable. Could you please post that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for me ...

Responsible for the behaviour is the column-mapping-property of the column. Switching it from ***MappingType.Hidden***    to    ***MappingType.Element*** prevents the internal column-generation-algorithm from filtering the column out.

```
List<DataColumn> ldc_recover = new List<DataColumn>(); 

foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable1.Columns)
{
    if (dataColumn.ColumnMapping == MappingType.Hidden)
    {
        dataColumn.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
        ldc_recover.Add(dataColumn);
    }
}

// Fill the datagridview with data from datatable
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;

// Restore the previous columnmapping-property
foreach (DataColumn dc_enum in ldc_recover)
{
    dc_enum.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
}
```